# Need help on implementing Search option

Tags: android

Friend's 
         I have list of places in my database,when i click search option from my UI i have to fetch the data from database and the listed below the textbox,and then i select the corresponding place to search on google maps,it works fine for android platform below 2.1,but when i use 2.2 i'm getting force close Exception.Is there any other way to implement search option in android.

here the exception i'm getting in 2.2 platform
**10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319): error changing cursor and caching columns
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:347)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:320)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.database.MatrixCursor.getLong(MatrixCursor.java:255)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:127)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:156)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1248)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1137)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1019)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1002)
10-22 14:14:21.442: ERROR/SuggestionsAdapter(319):     at android.app.SearchDialog.onDataSetChanged(SearchDialog.java:612)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Geocoder .getFromLocationName method there seems to be problem in the emulator with API level 8 (SDK 2.2) target in Eclipse. see  [link text](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816)

If you switch your target to API level 7, it may work properly for you.

Whoops! you edited whilst I was composing this, my suggestion might not work

Comment: Correct i had the same issue and believe its a bug in the emulator should work fine on device - for testing use api levl 7 if you can (or a real phone)

Comment: I'm checked upon both device and emulator,still it's not fixed,i'm using map api 1.6 version,whether i have to use higher version map api  or else what i do.I'm using the below permission <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4"
  android:maxSdkVersion="8" />,whether i need to change anyting from manifest or i have to higher version map api